# Rails could not find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

when tried to start server `rails s` i have got

```
 Could not find minitest-5.9.0 in any of the sources
    Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

i did `gem install minitest -v 5.9.0`

Successfully installed minitest-5.9.0

1 gem installed

also `gem list`

```
minitest (5.9.0, 4.7.5)
```

but when i try `rails s` again i received the same error.

How could i fix it?

Comment: Did you install the gem on the same ruby version that you are using in rails? And as you can see in the error, you should run `bundle install` instead of `gem install` so it would change your `Gemfile.lock`. `gem install` just installs the gem on your system, but does not add it to app dependency list

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle install
```

If you have tried that, try

```
bundle update
```

This will update your gems and your gemfile.lock

Answer (score 1):

Best to specify the version you want in your Gemfile, at present you have 2 versions which will be causing the conflicts.

Something like `gem 'minitest ', '~> 5.90'` would do the trick. Once you have done this do `bundle update` this will ensure you update Gemfile to use the correct version of specified gem